# How to Update a column in Scala which is in Date Format

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Need help in Spark Scala to write the code for below issue.
I have a file having records like below.

```
aaa|2019-07-11 02:15:50

bbb|2019-07-03 22:21:50

vvv|2019-07-03 19:30:40

bzx|2019-07-11 02:15:30

rrr|2019-06-24 01:29:10

mmm|2019-06-23 20:35:05

qqq|2019-07-12 08:10:15

eee|2019-07-11 01:49:30

iii|2019-06-23 22:31:45
```

I have split the file and took the 2nd column

```
val file = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", """|""").load(pathOfDumpfile).toDF()
```

now I need to add "0000-00-00 00:00:05" to all the
values of the file (second column that is in date format) and save it as file like below

```
aaa|2019-07-11 02:15:55

bbb|2019-07-03 22:21:55

vvv|2019-07-03 19:30:45

bzx|2019-07-11 02:15:35

rrr|2019-06-24 01:29:15

mmm|2019-06-23 20:35:10

qqq|2019-07-12 08:10:20

eee|2019-07-11 01:49:35

iii|2019-06-23 22:31:50
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can add + 5 seconds to all the records in file/column.

Will really be helpful. After adding in Date time field, the second or minute should change , it shouldn't effect the date like its  2019-07-11 23:59:59 then even adding 1 to the second it will be 2019-07-12 00:00:00. I want to add but doesn't want to change the date so how I can do this the date shouldn't be changed only there should be a change in minute or second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can you do by using unix_timestamp

```
scala>  var dfv = Seq(("aaa","2019-07-11 23:59:59"),("bbb","2019-07-03 22:21:50"),("vvv","2019-07-03 19:30:40"),("bzx","2019-07-11 02:15:30"),("rrr","2019-06-24 01:29:10"),("mmm","2019-06-23 20:35:05"),("qqq","2019-07-12 08:10:15"),("eee","2019-07-11 01:49:30"),("iii","2019-06-23 22:31:45")).toDF("value","_date")

scala> dfv.show
+-----+-------------------+
|value|              _date|
+-----+-------------------+
|  aaa|2019-07-11 23:59:59|
|  bbb|2019-07-03 22:21:50|
|  vvv|2019-07-03 19:30:40|
|  bzx|2019-07-11 02:15:30|
|  rrr|2019-06-24 01:29:10|
|  mmm|2019-06-23 20:35:05|
|  qqq|2019-07-12 08:10:15|
|  eee|2019-07-11 01:49:30|
|  iii|2019-06-23 22:31:45|
+-----+-------------------+

scala> dfv.withColumn("_date_v1",when(date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"_date")),"HH:mm:ss ")>"23:59:55",$"_date").otherwise(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"_date")+5,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))).show
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|value|              _date|           _date_v1|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  aaa|2019-07-11 23:59:59|2019-07-11 23:59:59|
|  bbb|2019-07-03 22:21:50|2019-07-03 22:21:55|
|  vvv|2019-07-03 19:30:40|2019-07-03 19:30:45|
|  bzx|2019-07-11 02:15:30|2019-07-11 02:15:35|
|  rrr|2019-06-24 01:29:10|2019-06-24 01:29:15|
|  mmm|2019-06-23 20:35:05|2019-06-23 20:35:10|
|  qqq|2019-07-12 08:10:15|2019-07-12 08:10:20|
|  eee|2019-07-11 01:49:30|2019-07-11 01:49:35|
|  iii|2019-06-23 22:31:45|2019-06-23 22:31:50|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

let me know if you have any question related to the same.

Comment: Hi, can you help me here. How I can give variable as column name rather the hard coded column name (_date) in unix_timestamp($"_date")+5 https://stackoverflow.com/users/5303116/mahesh-gupta

Comment: @Arush70  if you have a single column of date and you want to add 5 seconds in each row. so you have to do if you will use withColumn

Comment: Hi Mahesh, yeah got the answer but the thing is the column name lets say _date I need to call this from config.yml file through a variable so how I can do so. in config file I have added a= _date and a is defined as String in code so  when trying to add a in unix_timestamp($"_date")+5 as unix_timestamp(a)+5 getting error 'a' is string need column name. So can you help how to add this https://stackoverflow.com/users/5303116/mahesh-gupta

Comment: try wrapping the column name string in _col_ like: unix_timestamp(col(a))+5

Comment: so @Arush70 try to get that column name using sc.getConf.get()

Comment: thanks it worked https://stackoverflow.com/users/10622280/pritish & https://stackoverflow.com/users/5303116/mahesh-gupta

Comment: Need one more help, After adding in Date time field, one the second or minute should change , it shouldn't effect the date like its  2019-07-11 23:59:59 then even adding 1 to the second it will be 2019-07-12 00:00:00. I want to add but doesn't want to change the date. Can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/10622280/pritish https://stackoverflow.com/users/5303116/mahesh-gupta

Comment: @Arush70 i have updated the Answer based on your requierment.don't forget to upvote the answer.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/5303116/mahesh-gupta , really thanks for your quick help .

Comment: need one more help, for achieving this, I have LEFT_Join two tables file1 and file2 as I need all the records from file1 in final CSV. So I need to only change the dates of the 'id' present in file2 only. How I can do this ? please help https://stackoverflow.com/users/5303116/mahesh-gupta

Comment: @could you please add sample example in existing question if it is related to same question

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of a custom udf, like:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

val file = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", """|""").load(pathOfDumpfile).toDF("a", "b")

val timeUDF = udf((x: java.sql.Timestamp) => new java.sql.Timestamp(time.getTime + 5000)) //getTime returns ms

file.select(col("a"), timeUDF(col("b")))
.write(...)
```

Comment: UDF is an overkill here since we already have built-in date/time funtions in Spark SQL that are perfectly capable for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use INTERVAL syntax in spark.

Using Dataframe:

```
val foo = spark.sql(""" select current_timestamp as ts """)
foo.select($"ts", $"ts" + expr("INTERVAL 5 SECONDS") as "ts_plus").show(false)
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|ts                     |ts_plus                |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|2019-09-16 10:33:17.626|2019-09-16 10:33:22.626|
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Using Spark SQL:

```
foo.createOrReplaceTempView("fooView")
spark.sql(""" select ts, ts + INTERVAL 5 seconds from fooView""").show(false)
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
|ts                     |CAST(ts + interval 5 seconds AS TIMESTAMP)|
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
|2019-09-16 10:35:12.847|2019-09-16 10:35:17.847                   |
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
```